# How to get value of enum throw retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a enum of some values, called Counter

```
enum class Counter{
    none,
    few,
    many
}
```

And I want to get value of this enum in my model, using retrofit, so I created an object

```
data class Test(
        var param1: String?,
        var param2: String?,
        var counter: Counter?,
)
```

But when I'm using this like model for my Retrofit method, I'm getting only param1 and param 2, although response from my server is `{"param1": "String1", "param2": "String2", "counter": "many"}`

How to get value of counter, don't using in model `var counter: String?`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your enum like this

```
enum class Counter{
    @SerializedName("none")
    none("none"),

    @SerializedName("few")
    few("few"),

    @SerializedName("many")
    many("many")
}
```

Comment: what happen if server return a new enum element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JsonDeserializer` to do custom deserialization for your network calls.

```
class TestDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<Test> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Test {
        val obj = json.asJsonObject

        val param1 = obj.get("param1")?.asString
        val param2 = obj.get("param2")?.asString

        val counter = when(obj.get("counter")?.asString) {
            "none" -> Counter.none
            "few" -> Counter.few
            "many" -> Counter.many
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Counter type unknown.")
        }

        return Test(param1, param2, counter)
    }
}
```

And you just need to register it when you're creating your Retrofit client.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Test::class.java, TestDeserializer())
        .create()

return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
```